# MKDIR 3 levels above using php

Tags: php

```
level1/level2/level3/CWD/mkdir.php
```

Name of Level1 is not known; is user specified & can be anything. Name of level2 & level3 is known and will remain static.
Current Working Directory contains mkdir.php file that is required to create a directory in level1 with user provided name.
The mkdir.php file below does the job, but don't know whether it's the correct way. Want experts to approve and advice. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['Name']))
    {   
    $newdir = $_POST['Name'];
    $dirname = "..\\$newdir";   

    $step1 = "..\\CWD";     
    $step2 = "..\\$step1";      
    $step3 = "..\\$step2\\$dirname";    

    if (mkdir($step3, 0777, true))
        {
        echo "dir created successfully";
        }
        else
        {
        echo  "dir not created";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running `mkdir.php` you can use `dirname()` consecutively until you reach `level1`.

Also, it's important to sanitize your input data to prevent malicious users from creating "rogue" directories on your system.

```
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Name', FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array('options' => array(
    'regexp' => '/^\w+$/',
    'flags' => FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE,
)));

if (!is_null($name)) {
    $base = dirname(dirname(dirname(__DIR__)));
    //      level1  level2  level3  CWD
    $path = sprintf('%s/%s', $base, $name);

    mkdir($path, 0777, true);
}
```

Comment: dirname at level1 is not known. It is a domain name and can be anything e.g. sample.com, example.com etc. However, thanks for the sanitation codes, but gives error of `unknown ";"... on line...` . Do I need to alter or add something to it?

Comment: @CodeCruncher My code doesn't assume anything about the name of level1, so this should work.

Comment: What about the error due to the sanitation codes?  Is it due to a missing `)` ?

Comment: @CodeCruncher Yes, my apologies, it compiled in my head though :)

Comment: Do I need to alter the code for anything else? Now, it's giving error for some `long name required` something like that. Thanks for your prompt help.

Comment: @CodeCruncher Without a verbatim error message I cant' really help you.

Comment: Never mind. That's another problem and must be having solutions somewhere around. Sorry, cannot extend discussion as SO rules prevent it. Thanks.

Comment: @CodeCruncher They don't really prevent it, they just suggest to use the chat feature; but since what you have mentioned is another problem I'm assuming that this code works okay for you?

Comment: :-( Sorry, being a newbie, have just 6 reps. Can't come to chat. Would have been so nice to chat with an expert like you.

Comment: @CodeCruncher No hurry, just get more rep first :)

Comment: Your code definitely works with my `if (isset)...` but gives a notice of `Use of undefined constant FILTER_REGEXP...` and warning of `filter_input() expects parameter 3 to be long...` with your sanitation codes.

Comment: Getting this `Warning: filter_input(): 'regexp' option missing in C:\User\xampp\htdocs\level1\level2\level3\CWD\makedir.php on line 5`  It takes time to check out your code as server is on another partition. Thanks for bearing with me.

Answer (score 0):

1. why to use \ instead of /
2. you are using too many variables, you can write path to dir where to create new dir with one line
3. $_POST['Name'] should be sanitized because it can contain ../ in it so it will make directory in wrong dir

Shorter and cleaner solution:

```
if(isset($_POST['Name'])) {

    $new_dir_name = $_POST['Name'];

    // it should work on linux and windows
    $new_dir_path = '../../../../'; # '/' should be at the end!!!

    //use this if one above doesn't work on windows
    //$new_dir_path = '..\\..\\..\\..\\'; 

    if(mkdir($new_dir_path.$new_dir_name, 0777, true)) {
        echo "dir created successfully";
    }
    else {
        echo  "dir not created";
    }
}
```

Comment: Tested your code. Creates dir one level above level1 in xammp i.e. in htdocs. Deleting last ..\\ creates in level1. Is end '/' required if CWD is specified e.g `../../CWD` ?

Comment: / is required because $new_dir_path.$new_dir_name. Otherwise it will create dir in one level under and dir ill be level2$_POST['Name']

Comment: That was exactly what was happening before and I couldn't understand why it was happening. Thanks for the clarification.